# Python : Count dynamic row

Tags: python, kivy

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy 1.10.0` . I am adding dynamic row using `+Add More` button.
I am using `on_text` event into every dynamic `TextInput` . Can someone help me that how to count `dynamic` row `on_text` event ?
In this image you can see `2 rows`.When i type into any `TextInput` then `on_text` event call.At this time how to count total number of rows?

[image]

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def count_row(self):
        print('count row')


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        #self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.root


test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        size_hint_x: .8
        on_text: root.count_row()


display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"


        Rows:
            id: rows
```

Comment: explain yourself better, what do you mean *by count dynamic row on_text event.*?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for that.I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an element to notify another then you must use properties, in your case `NumericProperty`, and create a binding between them.

```
...
class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    row_count = NumericProperty(0)
    def count_row(self):
        print('count row', self.row_count)

class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        row = Row(button_text=str(self.row_count))
        self.add_widget(row)
        row.row_count = self.row_count
        self.bind(row_count= row.setter("row_count"))
...
```